# GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pull_number}/merge returns 404

Tags: rest, github, github-api, github-api-v3

***Request***

`curl --location --request GET 'https://api.github.com/repos/gittestapi123/DataStructure/pulls/1/files' \`

Above GET API returns 200 OK

***Reponse***

```
    {
        "sha": "9f4b6d8bfeaf44aaa69872286163784706d1b053",
        "filename": "testFile1",
        "status": "added",
        "additions": 1,
        "deletions": 0,
        "changes": 1,
        "blob_url": "https://github.com/gittestapi123/DataStructure/blob/266f3f884286b84f9d3b50a18e2a2534007a406b/testFile1",
        "raw_url": "https://github.com/gittestapi123/DataStructure/raw/266f3f884286b84f9d3b50a18e2a2534007a406b/testFile1",
        "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/gittestapi123/DataStructure/contents/testFile1?ref=266f3f884286b84f9d3b50a18e2a2534007a406b",
        "patch": "@@ -0,0 +1 @@\n+This is a test file"
    }]
```

But for the same pull request If I submit GET request for [GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pull_number}/merge](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#check-if-a-pull-request-has-been-merged) I get 404
(Even If I include valid authentication header)

***Request***

`curl --location --request GET 'https://api.github.com/repos/gittestapi123/DataStructure/pulls/1/merge' \`

***Reponse***

```
{
    "message": "Not Found",
    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/pulls#check-if-a-pull-request-has-been-merged" }
```

I want to check if a pull request has been merged or not using the above API. Someone please please help on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can see that it is *not merged* because you got a 404.  In the documentation that you linked to:

> Response if pull request has been merged
>
> Status: 204 No Content
>
> **Not Found if pull request has not been merged**
>
> **Status: 404 Not Found**

(emphasis mine).

Comment: thanks @Edward. The request has a valid pull request. In my post, you can see I get 200 responses for /pulls/1/files GET requests. The pull request exists and it is mergeable

Comment: Yes, `/pulls/1/merge` responds differently than `/pulls/1/files`.  For `.../merge` you get a 404 because it has not yet been merged.  When you merge it you will get a 204.